# Must I use ActiveXObject to open a powerpoint presentation in html

Tags: html, macos, powerpoint, activex

I have the following code snippet which simply opens a Powerpoint presentation and calls a VBA macro.

```
function CallVBA()  
{   
    var App;  
    App = new ActiveXObject("PowerPoint.Application");
    App.Visible = true;
    App.Presentations.Open("D:\\Jonathan\\PPtHymns\\b.pptm");
    App.Run("Doit");
}
```

While this works fine on Windows, it does not work on a Mac because of using ActiveX objects.
Is there another way of opening a Powerpoint presentation within a html page?
This may appear to be trivial, but I wish use code to add several new slides and text into the presentation and then run the presentation manually when done.

Answer (score 0):

There appears to be no alternative at present.
As I wanted to build up slides from Excel spreadsheets, the only way to make this happen on both Mac and PC is to create a tab delimited file output from excel. Open the powerpoint app and use javascript/typescript in Script Lab.
So far this can not be done 100% as I can not see any javascript/typescript api's for inserting audio and text shapes and setting slide tansition properties. Perhaps I have missed them. Would someone please confirm?
Many thanks.